# dplyr: sum daily values per year but don't sum "repeated" daily values

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `df`that has daily values of `rain` for two `year`s (2003 and 2004) at two `site`s

```
set.seed(123)
date <- rep(as.Date(seq(as.Date("2003-01-01"), 
                        as.Date("2004-12-31"), by = 1), 
                    format="%Y-%m-%d"), 2)
site <- c(rep("Site_1", 731), rep("Site_2", 731))
rain <- c(as.numeric(sample(1.1e6:87e6, 731, replace=T)),
          as.numeric(sample(4.5e5:56e5, 731, replace=T)))
df <- data.frame(date, site, rain)
```

and `df1` that has monthly measurements of two parameters `param_A` and `param_B` at each of the two sites. For the two parameters, there are sometimes more than one measurement per day.

```
set.seed(123)
date <- rep(c(as.Date("2003-01-05"),as.Date("2003-02-12"), as.Date("2003-03-07"), as.Date("2003-04-07"),
           as.Date("2003-05-13"),as.Date("2003-06-17"), as.Date("2003-07-16"), as.Date("2003-08-23"),
           as.Date("2003-09-24"),as.Date("2003-10-18"), as.Date("2003-11-08"), as.Date("2003-12-28"),
           rep(as.Date("2003-03-01"), 3), rep(as.Date("2003-05-14"), 3), rep(as.Date("2003-08-21"), 3),
           as.Date("2004-01-14"),as.Date("2004-02-02"), as.Date("2004-03-17"), as.Date("2004-04-03"),
           as.Date("2004-05-05"),as.Date("2004-06-17"), as.Date("2004-07-04"), as.Date("2004-08-08"),
           as.Date("2004-09-16"),as.Date("2004-10-24"), as.Date("2004-11-09"), as.Date("2004-12-07"),
           rep(as.Date("2004-09-07"), 4), rep(as.Date("2004-10-27"), 2), rep(as.Date("2004-12-14"), 4)), 4)
site <- c(rep("Site_1", 86), rep("Site_2", 86))
parameter <- rep(c(rep("param_A", 43), rep("param_B", 43)), 2)
value <- c(runif(43, 0.05, 2.3)/1e6, 
           runif(43, 0.03, 3.1)/1e6,
           runif(43, 0.004, 0.09)/1e6,
           runif(43, 0.001, 0.07)/1e6) 
df1 <- data.frame(date, site, parameter, value)
```

I merged the two data.frames (`df` and `df1`) together into one data.frame `df2`

```
df2 <- merge(df, df1, by= c("date", "site"), all=T)
```

For each site, I want to calculate for each `year`, for each `parameter`, a variable let's name it `saturation` where it equals

```
(sum(rain*value)/sum(rain)) for days where value is not NA * sum(rain for whole year)
```

[I did it as below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559598/dplyr-sum-of-daily-values-for-whole-year-and-sum-of-specific-daily-values-in-th)

```
library(dplyr)
df_fin <- df2 %>%
  mutate(year = factor(format(date, "%Y"))) %>%
  arrange(site, year, parameter)  %>%
  group_by(site, year, parameter ) %>% 
  summarise(sum_rain = sum(rain), 
            specific_days = sum(rain*value, na.rm=TRUE)/sum(rain[!is.na(value)])) %>% 
  mutate(saturation = sum_rain * specific_days)
```

At each of the two sites, `param_A` and `param_B` have, in few days, more than one measurement per day. As a result, when calculating the sum of `rain` in the formula, the repeated rain value per day is being added which increase the `sum(daily rain values)` per year.

Is there a way to keep one rain value per day and not to add up these repeated daily values?

**UPDATE**

To be more specific, the `sum()` of daily of values of `rain` using `df` will be as below

```
library(dplyr)
df_1 <- df %>%
  mutate(year = factor(format(date, "%Y"))) %>%
  arrange(site, year)  %>%
  group_by(site, year) %>% 
  summarise(sum_rain = sum(rain))

df_1
#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: site [?]

#    site   year    sum_rain
#  (fctr) (fctr)       (dbl)
#1 Site_1   2003 16039370227
#2 Site_1   2004 16170122189
#3 Site_2   2003  1078275774
#4 Site_2   2004  1090111362
```

Whereas in `df_fin`, `sum_rain` is different from above

```
df_fin <- df2 %>%
  mutate(year = factor(format(date, "%Y"))) %>%
  arrange(site, year, parameter)  %>%
  group_by(site, year, parameter ) %>% 
  summarise(sum_rain = sum(rain), 
            specific_days = sum(rain*value, na.rm=TRUE)/sum(rain[!is.na(value)])) %>% 
  mutate(saturation = sum_rain * specific_days)

df_fin
     site   year parameter    sum_rain specific_days  saturation
   (fctr) (fctr)    (fctr)       (dbl)         (dbl)       (dbl)
1  Site_1   2003   param_A   916392248  1.342250e-06 1230.027083
2  Site_1   2003   param_B   916392248  1.263414e-06 1157.783068
3  Site_1   2003        NA 15413670047           NaN         NaN
4  Site_1   2004   param_A   949808653  1.253945e-06 1191.007549
5  Site_1   2004   param_B   949808653  1.517257e-06 1441.104187
6  Site_1   2004        NA 15623884439           NaN         NaN
7  Site_2   2003   param_A    59690558  5.113758e-08    3.052431
8  Site_2   2003   param_B    59690558  3.592397e-08    2.144322
9  Site_2   2003        NA  1038708704           NaN         NaN
10 Site_2   2004   param_A    76792434  4.508143e-08    3.461913
11 Site_2   2004   param_B    76792434  2.958886e-08    2.272201
12 Site_2   2004        NA  1035805843           NaN         NaN
```

I want `sum_rain` in `df_fin` to **be the same** as `sum_rain` in `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    group_by(site, Year = year(date)) %>% 
    mutate(sum_rain = sum(rain)) %>% 
    full_join(., df1, by = c('date', 'site')) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(parameter)) %>%  
    group_by(parameter, add=TRUE) %>%
    summarise(sum_rain = first(sum_rain),
              specific_days = sum(rain*value, na.rm=TRUE)/sum(rain[!is.na(value)])) %>%
    mutate(saturation = sum_rain * specific_days)
#     site  Year parameter    sum_rain    specific_days  saturation
#  <fctr> <dbl>    <fctr>       <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 Site_1  2003   param_A 16039370227 0.00000134224955 21528.83747
#2 Site_1  2003   param_B 16039370227 0.00000126341430 20264.36967
#3 Site_1  2004   param_A 16170122189 0.00000125394472 20276.43941
#4 Site_1  2004   param_B 16170122189 0.00000151725738 24534.23720
#5 Site_2  2003   param_A  1078275774 0.00000005113758    55.14042
#6 Site_2  2003   param_B  1078275774 0.00000003592397    38.73595
#7 Site_2  2004   param_A  1090111362 0.00000004508143    49.14378
#8 Site_2  2004   param_B  1090111362 0.00000002958886    32.25515
```

If we want the NA rows as well, remove the `filter` step

```
df %>%
     group_by(site, Year = year(date)) %>% 
     mutate(sum_rain = sum(rain)) %>% 
     full_join(., df1, by = c('date', 'site')) %>% 
     group_by(parameter, add=TRUE) %>%
     summarise(sum_rain = first(sum_rain),
               specific_days = sum(rain*value,
                    na.rm=TRUE)/sum(rain[!is.na(value)])) %>%
     mutate(saturation = sum_rain * specific_days)

#     site  Year parameter    sum_rain    specific_days  saturation
#   <fctr> <dbl>    <fctr>       <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>
#1  Site_1  2003   param_A 16039370227 0.00000134224955 21528.83747
#2  Site_1  2003   param_B 16039370227 0.00000126341430 20264.36967
#3  Site_1  2003        NA 16039370227              NaN         NaN
#4  Site_1  2004   param_A 16170122189 0.00000125394472 20276.43941
#5  Site_1  2004   param_B 16170122189 0.00000151725738 24534.23720
#6  Site_1  2004        NA 16170122189              NaN         NaN
#7  Site_2  2003   param_A  1078275774 0.00000005113758    55.14042
#8  Site_2  2003   param_B  1078275774 0.00000003592397    38.73595
#9  Site_2  2003        NA  1078275774              NaN         NaN
#10 Site_2  2004   param_A  1090111362 0.00000004508143    49.14378
#11 Site_2  2004   param_B  1090111362 0.00000002958886    32.25515
#12 Site_2  2004        NA  1090111362              NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @aelwan  Could you use `mutate` instead of `summarise` and then do `unique` to get the dates as well.

Comment: @Many thanks for your time and help. Regarding mutate, it worked fine. For unique, where it should be?

Comment: @aelwan In your example, there were no duplicate rows, so all the rows will be selected

Comment: @aelwan Can you post that as separate question to understand it better